# RDP - Non VPC EC2 instance to VPC (Public) EC2 Instance: Not Working

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp, vpc

I have few EC2 instances across VPC and non-VPC.

VPC Instance
VPC-Dev1
VPC-Dev2

Without VPC
EC2-Dev1
EC2-Dev2

I can access (RDP) all the servers from outside world. I have given RDP access to all (0.0.0.0/0) to ensure that I am not missing out anything.

However, I can't access VPC-Dev1 from EC2-Dev1 or vice-a-versa. Is there any specific firewalls related setup I need do to allow AWS instances to get access to each other?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the calls using the private IPs, try using the public IPs.

Comment: Hi - I am trying using Public IP